# Reset dropdown values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have 3 cascading dropdowns in my page. By default on page load for all my dropdowns I have a default option like below

```
--Select--
```

So when user tries to select this -- Select-- option in dropdown it throws and error.

**Error Message:**

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed
```

I have a gridview in my page and when I select my first dropdown value the gridview populates data. And when I select my second dropdown value, combination of first two dropdown values wil be populated in the grid. And now when I select this --Select-- option in second dropdown the gridview says 0 record found instead of displaying first dropwdown values. Also when I select the option --Select-- for first dropdown it has to return all the values of the grid data that happens in page load.

```
ddlGroup.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
```

**Code Behind:**

**1st Dropdown:**

```
 protected void ddlDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "select distinct(Group) from Application where Date = '" + ddlDate.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ddlGroup.DataSource = dt;
        ddlGroup.DataTextField = "Group";
        ddlGroup.DataBind();
        ddlGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        conn.Close();
        ddlCode.Items.Clear();
        ddlCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        DataTable dtDate = DataRepository.GetDate(ddlDate.Text);
        gvDetails.DataSource = dtDate;
        gvDetails.DataBind();           
}
```

**2nd DropDown**

```
 protected void ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "select distinct(Code) from Application where Date = '" + ddlDate.Text + "' and Group='" + ddlGroup.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ddlCode.DataSource = dt;
        ddlCode.DataTextField = "Code";
        ddlCode.DataBind();
        ddlCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        conn.Close();
        DataTable dtGroup = DataRepository.GetGroup(ddlDate.Text, ddlGroup.Text);
        gvDetails.DataSource = dtGroup;
        gvDetails.DataBind();                                  
}
```

**3rd Dropdown:**

```
protected void ddlCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtCode = DataRepository.GetCode(ddlDate.Text, ddlGroup.Text, ddlCode.Text);
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtCode;
    gvDetails.DataBind();        
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Please clarify.

Comment: Pls lemme know which part?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it is not easy to see what is going on ... the text of the Item you insert is "--Select--" but what is the value? Are you using the value to populate your gridview? At the moment the value will be "--Select--". Is that what you are using to populate the Gridview ... if (ddlGroup.SelectedValue.ToString() == "--Select--"   ?

Comment: @karz - Updated my post with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the dropdown value before binding gridview.

whenever you change the selected value to --SELECT-- it calls `ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged` function.

try:

```
     protected void ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if(ddlGroup.Text!="--Select--")
{
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "select distinct(Code) from Application where Date = '" + ddlDate.Text + "' and Group='" + ddlGroup.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            ddlCode.DataSource = dt;
            ddlCode.DataTextField = "Code";
            ddlCode.DataBind();
            ddlCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
            conn.Close();
            DataTable dtGroup = DataRepository.GetGroup(ddlDate.Text, ddlGroup.Text);
            gvDetails.DataSource = dtGroup;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
}

else
{
// call ddlDate_SelectedIndexChanged 
}                                  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
```

Your code ...

```
string strQuery = "select distinct(Code) from Application where Date = '" + ddlDate.Text + "' and Group='" + ddlGroup.Text + "'";
```

... where are you checking that the values in ddlDate.Text and ddlGroup.Text make sense?

if your query ends up as:

Select Distinct(code) from Application where Date = '--Select--' and Group = '--Select--'

it, presumably, won't return anything?

Just as an aside - your code is asking for trouble. Why don't you put opening your database connection in a try catch finally block so you can make sure you always close the connection.

How do you handle errors thrown by the call to the database?

Comment: But When I select this -- Select-- in my second dropdown I still see 0 record found.

Comment: Can you post the code that runs when you select an item in your second dropdownlist and the code you are using to bind your gridview.